# Waiting for callback functions to return in iOS/iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, asynchronous, callback

I need to make a call `getValuesAndCalculate` in my app, which should return only after doing its work. However, for doing its work, it needs to get records from a server, which has to be done through an async call. The server data is received through a callback function. Thus, in  `getValuesAndCalculate` I need to wait till I have the data before proceeding with the calculations. How do I implement this?

Comment: go for protocols with your own logics..

Comment: Call getValuesAndCalculate from the server data callback function?

Comment: Have a look at [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) You can do ASync request and use a block to handle the response.

Comment: i am not sure if this is the case ,but if u are posting some data to the server and waiting for response from it u can use the delegate method - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response    .this gets fired when the response from the server is received

Answer (score 2):

## Use protocols and delegates :

delegates are nothing but you assigning an object from your class to a object on the server side .
The server can use this object to call a method on your client side code.

Comment: Or you can use NSNotificationCenter. It's the same.
Please don't use a kind of loop or similar! You don't have to block your app until response comes. Your app has to WAIT until something wake up it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using NSRunloop till you get the data from the server.

For eg :

while (!isFinished)
  {
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode  beforeDate:1.0]
  }

Answer (score 0):

You can implement Threads for this question i.e,

```
// in main thread
// start activity indicator
NSThread *calculateThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(getValuesAndCalculate) object:nil];
[calculateThread start];
// End of Main thread



- (void)getValuesAndCalculate
{
    // Perform transactions with server 
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(continueMainThreadOperations) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
}
```

Thats it!